# Background routing task in iOS app

Tags: ios, background, routes

I'm trying to create a routing app and, as Google Map does, I'd like to implement some kind of background routing task as in the screenshot.

Is there any flag to activate or method to call in order to achieve this?

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC7rD.png)

Answer (score 0):

See documentation of startUpdatingLocation in CLLocationManager.